# Passing a char pointer array to a function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game and I want to pass my 2d array of the tic tac toe board positions to my function that draws the updated board. I want the parameter value of my function "updateBoard" to be able to take in the memory adress of the board from main so I can use it all throughout my program without worrying about scope. I am getting an error as so when i compile it:

> error C2664: 'updateBoard' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char (*)[3][3]' to 'char *[][3]' 1> Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

heres my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void updateBoard (char *n[3][3])
{

}
int getMove ()
{
int input;
cout <<"\n";
cout <<"1 for square 1| 2 for square 2| and so on...  : ";
cin >>input;

return 0;
}

int main ()
{
const int WIDTH = 3;
const int HEIGHT = 3;
char board [WIDTH][HEIGHT] = {' ', ' ', ' ',
                              ' ', ' ', ' ',
                              ' ', ' ', ' '};
updateBoard(&board);
char f;
cin >>f;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following way

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int WIDTH = 3;
const int HEIGHT = 3;

typedef char TBoard [WIDTH][HEIGHT];

void updateBoard ( TBoard board, int width )
{

}

int main ()
{
TBoard board = {' ', ' ', ' ',
                ' ', ' ', ' ',
                ' ', ' ', ' '};
updateBoard( board, WIDTH);
char f;
cin >>f;
}
```

As for your error then the function parameter shall be defined as

```
void updateBoard (char ( *n )[3][3])
{

}
```

`char ( *n )[3][3]` means pointer to a two-dimensional array while

`char * n[3][3]` means a two dimensional array of pointers `char *`

And inside the function you should to write

```
( *n )[i][j]
```

to access the element with indexes i and j.